# Statistical test to see whether dataset represents reality or not

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, hidden-markov-model

I have a dataset consisting data from 3 persons (2 male, 1 female) for a total of 56 days. Data consists time, location and human activity (3 weeks for male 1 and female, 2 weeks for male 2). I applied HMM to recognize human activity from time and location information and got pretty good accuracy (97%).

The sample size for each subjects are:

Subject. --- Sample Size

Subject 1.   486

Subject 2.   750

Subject 3.   850

As I have a small number of subjects, I was wondering whether I can do a statistical test to see whether the dataset represents the reality or not?

My question is: Is it possible to do some testing to see whether the accuracy which I got for 3 subjects can be true for 100 or more subjects.

Comment: I think you need to get standard error.

Comment: Could you please elaborate or point me in the right direction? I didn't get that. Thanks